# Can't set CornerRadius on TextBox style

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

I have the following style:

```
<Style x:Key="RoundedCornerControl" BasedOn="{x:Null}" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}"/>
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.WindowBrushKey}}"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource TextBoxBorder}"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="1"/>
    <Setter Property="AllowDrop" Value="true"/>
    <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}"/>
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.PanningMode" Value="VerticalFirst"/>
    <Setter Property="Stylus.IsFlicksEnabled" Value="False"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
                <Themes:ListBoxChrome x:Name="Bd" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" RenderMouseOver="{TemplateBinding IsMouseOver}" RenderFocused="{TemplateBinding IsKeyboardFocusWithin}" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                    <ScrollViewer x:Name="PART_ContentHost" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
                </Themes:ListBoxChrome>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                        <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Bd" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}}"/>
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextBrushKey}}"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <MultiTrigger>
            <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                <Condition Property="IsInactiveSelectionHighlightEnabled" Value="true"/>
                <Condition Property="IsSelectionActive" Value="false"/>
            </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
            <Setter Property="SelectionBrush" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.InactiveSelectionHighlightBrushKey}}"/>
        </MultiTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

I have tried searched for and found various resources on how to make the corners round, but everything I tried has caused some sort of syntax error or another.

Can someone please show me how to modify the default style above to make the corners rounded?

## Update

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
    <Border x:Name="border" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" CornerRadius="3" BorderThickness="2">
        <ScrollViewer x:Name="PART_ContentHost" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
    </Border>
    <Themes:ListBoxChrome x:Name="Bd" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" RenderMouseOver="{TemplateBinding IsMouseOver}" RenderFocused="{TemplateBinding IsKeyboardFocusWithin}" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
        <ScrollViewer x:Name="PART_ContentHost" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
    </Themes:ListBoxChrome>
    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
            <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Bd" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}}"/>
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextBrushKey}}"/>
        </Trigger>
    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
</ControlTemplate>
```

Comment: Where you set CornerRadius value in your code???

Comment: @RameshRams I have tried setting it many places but it was failing; so I provided the blank (default) style that I hoped someone could modify the right way.

Comment: Please see this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/327838/can-you-databind-to-cornerradius-via-wpf-styles .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the Border inside the ControlTemplate and specify the CornerRadius. For e.q.

```
<Border x:Name="border" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" CornerRadius="3" BorderThickness="2">
       <ScrollViewer x:Name="PART_ContentHost" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
</Border>
```

Update:

```
<Border x:Name="border" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" CornerRadius="3" BorderThickness="2">
     <Themes:ListBoxChrome x:Name="Bd" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" RenderMouseOver="{TemplateBinding IsMouseOver}" RenderFocused="{TemplateBinding IsKeyboardFocusWithin}" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
           <ScrollViewer x:Name="PART_ContentHost" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
     </Themes:ListBoxChrome>
</Border>
```

Comment: I have added the code inside the `ControlTemplate` tags but it gives me an error, "The property 'VisualTree' can only be set once."  I have updated my question with the code.

Comment: You cannot set ScrollViewer twice, try to add the <Theme> inside the border

Comment: I am not sure what you mean.  Where is the `<Theme>`?

Comment: Just "The property 'VisualTree' can only be set once."

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34549/discussion-between-martijn-van-put-and-user1477388)